# Special chars in variable's value get escaped

Tags: bash

Say I declare variable `var` as `var="ls | grep a"`. Then I would expect the command `$var` to work exactly as `ls | grep a`, but instead the `|` char is read as escaped `\|` so that it rather prints an error saying that no file named `\|`, `grep` or `a` is found.

My question is: how can I make Bash interpret `|` in `var`'s value as not escaped?

I have to use it in a `case` statement such as

```
var1="str1|str2"
var2="str3|str4"
case $option in
  ${var1} ) echo "It works! 1" ;;
  ${var2} ) echo "It works! 2" ;;
  *  ) echo "It does not work"
esac
```

**(edit2):** and make it return `It works! 1` if `$option` is either `str1` or `str2`, and `It works! 2` if `$option` is either `str3` or `str4`. That is because I am writing a function in which case patterns may change according to the user inputs.

Though I don't think it is relevant to know, I use `lxterminal` on Lubuntu 12.04 and `$BASH_VERSION` is `4.2.25(1)-release`.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It would be very helpful that you explain what your trying to achieve. It seems you're taking the wrong path when putting compound commands in a variable... there's probably a much more robust, safer, cleaner and easier way to achieve your goal. Please see [this link about the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Besides, parsing the output of `ls` is a very bad thing to do!

Comment: I just want to have a `case` statement whose patterns depend on the values of some variables. In order to achieve this I thought it best to use variables as patterns, but the problem is that the vertical line is read as `\|`. Any solution is fine to me, I just wrote what I tried.

Comment: I really have no idea what you want to do and why. If you try `case $var in` `*b*) echo "It works!";;` it will work.

Comment: E.g. if `var="a|b"` I would want `case $option in $var ) ...` to produce the same result as `case $option in a|b ) ...`, if `var="h|H|l|L` I would want `case $option in $var ) ...` to produce the same result as `case $option in h|H|l|L ) ...` and so on. Briefly speaking, I'd like the "`pattern )`" to be variable.

Comment: why do you have the patterns in a variable?

Comment: I was working on a kind of `menu()` function which asks the user to choose an input among a few choices listed. My goal is to use it in several other Bash functions, so I tried to be as general as possible.

Comment: For a menu, you can use the `select` bash builtin. `help select` for more info. This solution might be less clunky than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you for the tip, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this may be what you wish:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="a|b"
first_option=$(echo $var | cut -d"|" -f1)
second_option=$(echo $var | cut -d"|" -f2)

is_working? () {
  case $1 in 
    $first_option ) echo "It works!" ;;
    $second_option ) echo "It also works!" ;;
    *  ) echo "It does not work"
  esac
}

#1
option=a
is_working? $option

#2
option=b
is_working? $option

#2
option=c
is_working? $option
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but as @gniourf_gniourf commented I guess I wasn't very clear about what I meant. I would like the cases in the case statement to be variable as well as the option being tested. I slightly edited my question hoping it can clarify what I am looking for :)

Comment: @AndreasT Nothing more then simple, check my answer now.

Comment: Why reversing `option` and `var`? If `var="aa|b"` I would expect it "to work" if and only if `$option` is either `aa` or `b` but your first example would print `It works!` anyway. Besides, what if I had `case ${option} in ${var1} )...;; ${var2} )...`?

Comment: I mean, your code works only for a single char `${option}` value

Comment: @AndreasT Ok, try it now